# Recognize computer after a reformat

Tags: java

I need a way for a Java program to recognize a computer, even if the computers HDD have been wiped clean. Is there some ID or Serial that won't change that I can use. I would prefer if it could be done with pure java, so it could work for both windows and linux.

Comment: Check out this guide on [How to get MAC address in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/)

Comment: So the MAC address won't change, and will be unique for each computer?

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986732/how-to-get-a-unique-computer-identifier-in-java-like-disk-id-or-motherboard-id

Comment: As for a lot of questions (in life) the answer is: It depends, please read up on MAC addresses. TLDR: MAC addresses can be changed and devices can and often do have multiple MAC addresses

Answer (score 0):

A [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) address is unique & eternal number assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical network segment. MAC addresses are used as a network address for most IEEE 802 network technologies, including Ethernet and WiFi